# How to select parent and not child in CSS?

Tags: css

I have a menu which looks something like this:

```
<div class="myclass" >
    <ul>
        <li>
        <li>        <------- select parent li and not child li
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li> <------ then select only child li
                <li>
            </ul>
        <li>
        <li>
        <li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I need to style parent and child menus seperetely but I can't seem to get how to select them and style seperetely. Any help appreciated! :)

Comment: please edit putting closing </li>

Answer (score 2):

Select only higher-level `<li>`:

```
.myclass > ul > li
```

Select lower-level `<li>`:

```
.myClass > ul > li > ul > li
```

The key here is using the direct child selector `>`. See 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors.

Answer (score 0):

For parent you do like this :

```
.myclass > ul > li
```

And for child:

```
.myclass > ul > li > ul > li
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

for parent

```
.myClass > ul > li
```

Sample:

```js
$( ".myClass > ul > li" ).css( "color", "green" );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myClass" >
    <ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>
    <ul>
    <li>Tea</li>
    <li>Black Tea</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

for child

```
.myClass > ul > li > ul > li
```

Sample:

```js
$( ".myClass > ul > li > ul > li" ).css( "color", "green" );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myClass" >
    <ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>
    <ul>
    <li>Tea</li>
    <li>Black Tea</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
</div>
```